# Grouped Bar Plot with Multiple Numeric Fill Variables

Tags: ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm used to creating grouped bar plots like this:

```
new_data<-data%>%
mutate(new_variable=ifelse(variable<100, "Low", "High"))
ggplot(gap,aes(x=random_variable, fill=new_variable))+geom_bar()
```

Basically I create an additional column that distinguishes any numeric value in the original column I'm using for this example called "variable," and then using "ifelse" it knows how to categorize the new column called "new_variable"

However, can someone please help me separate the fill into three or more levels, for example:

```
<10, 10-19, 20-59, 50-100, >100
```

and then generate a grouped bar plot with multiple filled variables based on these numeric conditions?

Comment: You can use nested `ifelse`, or `case_when`: [case_when documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when).

Comment: Another option would be `cut` from base R. See `?cut`.